# Why isn't this a "homeomorphically irreducible tree of size $n=10$"

Tags: graph-theory

So good will hunting provides this problem: "draw all homeomorphically irreducible trees of size $n=10$".

The answer is this:

[image]

But I also got the following answer, and I don't understand why it's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Yours is isomorphic to the third tree in the first row.

Comment: Wow I was getting this exact same graph and was completely stumped as to why I couldn't find the solution. Thanks @LaarsHelenius

Answer (score 6):

Yours is isomorphic to the third tree in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is a correct tree however it's essentially the same components as the third tree from the left in the upper image that you provided so it would be redundant (can be arranged into two sets of three vertices and one set of four). Picture each dot like a hinge that can spin 360 degrees whenever you do homeomorphically irreducible trees.